# How to timeout early when trying to connect

Tags: python, timeout, rabbitmq, pika

I have an application that is trying to connect to a rabbitmq-server, but I want my application to timeout within a specified number of seconds if it cannot connect to the server.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to do it.

to clarify, it's when my producer tries to connect that I want to timeout earlier, because now It takes up to 20-30 seconds.

Comment: make a separate [thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) with a timer in it, after the timer close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library you're using makes use of the [socket module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket) (many do), a simple `import socket; socket.setdefaulttimeout( SECONDS )` will suffice

[edited to include the correction by Daniel Figueroa]

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar! Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction, although it's socket.setdefaulttimeout() to be really picky.